# Akka remoting- Cann't assign requested address

Tags: java, scala, netty, akka

I am trying an example of Akka-Remoting. Every time I start my remote actor system I get this exception

```
[INFO] [11/25/2013 18:50:19.811] [main] [Remoting] Starting remoting
Exception in thread "main" org.jboss.netty.channel.ChannelException: Failed to bind to: /10.147.137.44:2555
at org.jboss.netty.bootstrap.ServerBootstrap.bind(ServerBootstrap.java:272)
at akka.remote.transport.netty.NettyTransport$$anonfun$listen$1.apply(NettyTransport.scala:391)
at akka.remote.transport.netty.NettyTransport$$anonfun$listen$1.apply(NettyTransport.scala:388)
at scala.util.Success$$anonfun$map$1.apply(Try.scala:206)
at scala.util.Try$.apply(Try.scala:161)
at scala.util.Success.map(Try.scala:206)
at scala.concurrent.Future$$anonfun$map$1.apply(Future.scala:235)
at scala.concurrent.Future$$anonfun$map$1.apply(Future.scala:235)
at scala.concurrent.impl.CallbackRunnable.run(Promise.scala:32)
at akka.dispatch.BatchingExecutor$Batch$$anonfun$run$1.processBatch$1(BatchingExecutor.scala:67)
at akka.dispatch.BatchingExecutor$Batch$$anonfun$run$1.apply$mcV$sp(BatchingExecutor.scala:82)
at akka.dispatch.BatchingExecutor$Batch$$anonfun$run$1.apply(BatchingExecutor.scala:59)
at akka.dispatch.BatchingExecutor$Batch$$anonfun$run$1.apply(BatchingExecutor.scala:59)
at scala.concurrent.BlockContext$.withBlockContext(BlockContext.scala:72)
at akka.dispatch.BatchingExecutor$Batch.run(BatchingExecutor.scala:58)
at akka.dispatch.TaskInvocation.run(AbstractDispatcher.scala:42)
at akka.dispatch.ForkJoinExecutorConfigurator$AkkaForkJoinTask.exec(AbstractDispatcher.scala:386)
at scala.concurrent.forkjoin.ForkJoinTask.doExec(ForkJoinTask.java:260)
at scala.concurrent.forkjoin.ForkJoinPool$WorkQueue.runTask(ForkJoinPool.java:1339)
at scala.concurrent.forkjoin.ForkJoinPool.runWorker(ForkJoinPool.java:1979)
at scala.concurrent.forkjoin.ForkJoinWorkerThread.run(ForkJoinWorkerThread.java:107)
Caused by: java.net.BindException: Cannot assign requested address
at sun.nio.ch.Net.bind0(Native Method)
at sun.nio.ch.Net.bind(Net.java:444)
at sun.nio.ch.Net.bind(Net.java:436)
at sun.nio.ch.ServerSocketChannelImpl.bind(ServerSocketChannelImpl.java:214)
at sun.nio.ch.ServerSocketAdaptor.bind(ServerSocketAdaptor.java:74)
at org.jboss.netty.channel.socket.nio.NioServerBoss$RegisterTask.run(NioServerBoss.java:193)
at org.jboss.netty.channel.socket.nio.AbstractNioSelector.processTaskQueue(AbstractNioSelector.java:366)
at org.jboss.netty.channel.socket.nio.AbstractNioSelector.run(AbstractNioSelector.java:290)
at org.jboss.netty.channel.socket.nio.NioServerBoss.run(NioServerBoss.java:42)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:744)
```

Here is my *application.conf* details

```
remoteCalculator{
  akka {
  actor {
    provider = "akka.remote.RemoteActorRefProvider"
  }
  remote {
    transport = "akka.remote.netty.NettyRemoteTransport"
    log-received-messages = on
    log-sent-messages = on
    log-remote-lifecycle-events = on
    enabled-transports = ["akka.remote.netty.tcp"]
    netty.tcp {
      hostname = "10.147.137.44"
      port = 2555
      log-received-messages = on
      log-sent-messages = on
      log-remote-lifecycle-events = on
    }
   }
  }
}
```

I tried finding the possibility of another application listening to the port 2555 by executing following command

```
sudo netstat -anp | grep 2555
```

But it doesn't gives anything. Please help me find out the reason why the application is not able to bind on the configured address.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got the root cause of the problem. Actually it was not a configuration/proramming issue. I am working on a virtual host (Ubuntu) inside my window OS and I had not enabled the network bridge. So, the virtual host was not able to identify the *hostName*. After enabling the network bridge, the issue got solved.